# How secure is Aamazon Kinesis endpoint? Does the Kinesis Producer Library (KPL) securely sends messages to Kinesis endpoint?

Tags: security, https, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-kpl

I am building Amazon Kinesis based streaming data ingestion from on-prem data source. I can use the Kinesis Producer Library (KPL) to produce messages to Kinesis Data Stream. I wanted to know how secure is the data transfer/ingestion through KPL. Is it using a secure endpoint underneath or using any in-transit encryption? Kinesis Data Stream offers to encrypt data at rest. But in this case how about the data security while in transit before it gets written to Kinesis Shards?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have configured a different endpoint and protocol in the KPL, the 
communications to the AWS Kinesis endpoints are secured via HTTPS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#ak_region